# Processing large XML File in Mule

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I am trying to process a large XML file (~300MB) in Mule 4. I have been referring [this](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-split-big-XML-file-with-streaming-low-memory) article, but foreach shape throws error:
Scripting language error on expression '%dw 2.0 output application/xml --- payload.file'. Reason: Unable to call: Value Selector with arguments: (Binary, file). Reasons: - Expecting Type: Object, but got: Binary. |-- From: Object |- From: Value Selector(lhs: Object, rhs: Name) -> Any 1| %dw 2.0 output application/xml --- payload.file - Expecting Type: Array, but got: Binary.

**Update:**
I added a variable to save the payload with a mime type as XML and then set the payload with this variable, again with the mime type as XML. Now the foreach shape complains about:

```
"Trying to output second root, <record>, while writing Xml at ." evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0 output application/xml --- payload.file".
```

[image]

. I presume this could be happening because of the read shape which outputs binary. I tried using a transform shape after read and before for each but it stays in processing mode for way too long.

Here is the sample input file structure:

```
<file>
 <record>
  <WORK_ORDER>123</WORK_ORDER>
  <DESC>TEXT1</DESC>
  <STATUS_M>0</STATUS_M>
  <CODE>code1</CODE>
 </record>
 <record>
  <WORK_ORDER>124</WORK_ORDER>
  <DESC>TEXT2</DESC>
  <STATUS_M>1</STATUS_M>
  <CODE>code2</CODE>
 </record>
 <record>
  <WORK_ORDER>125</WORK_ORDER>
  <DESC>TEXT3</DESC>
  <STATUS_M>0</STATUS_M>
  <CODE>code3</CODE>
 </record>
</file>
```

Here is the code:

```
<flow name="streaming-poc-flow" doc:id="2b5e68a5-e3a9-4c7a-a114-c9516e9ac33e" >
    <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler" doc:id="a86b544d-d72e-4e11-8adf-aecc6f61d515" >
        <scheduling-strategy >
            <fixed-frequency frequency="5" timeUnit="MINUTES"/>
        </scheduling-strategy>
    </scheduler>
    <file:read doc:name="Read" doc:id="c6ddc341-0808-416a-935a-4d1fac9deafb" config-ref="File_Config" path="D:\unittest\WorkOrder.XML" outputMimeType="application/xml; streaming=true; collectionpath=file.record" target="varsXML">
        <non-repeatable-stream />
    </file:read>
    <set-payload value="#[vars.varsXML]" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="7a30359a-5989-4401-ac8b-c90e3cfd4d9d" mimeType="application/xml"/>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="75df909d-2ee1-4439-a987-168ed7d2408e" collection="#[%dw 2.0 &#10;output application/xml &#10;--- &#10;payload.file]" batchSize="100" rootMessageVariableName="record">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="de3f5603-a0e4-4234-b5bc-b61ab52b74db" message="File output: #[payload]" />
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

Is there any different approach I can take to process such large files?

Comment: What is the complete error?

Comment: Scripting language error on expression '%dw 2.0 output application/xml --- payload.file'. Reason: Unable to call: `Value Selector` with arguments: (`Binary`, `file`).
 Reasons:
 - Expecting Type: `Object`, but got: `Binary`.
  |-- From: `Object` 
  |- From: Value Selector(lhs: `Object`, rhs: `Name`) -> `Any`  
   1| %dw 2.0 output application/xml --- payload.file
                              
 - Expecting Type: `Array<Any>`, but got: `Binary`.

Comment: It doesn't show the line or flow path. Please remove the error handler and add the complete error message to the question.

Comment: The error appears on the same line where foreach starts.
" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0 output application/xml --- payload.file".
Element               : streaming-poc-flow/processors/2 @ unit-test-ground:unit-test-ground.xml:634 (For Each)
Element DSL           : <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="97621d93-0428-4ad2-aa39-560d68b0975d" batchSize="10000" collection="#[%dw 2.0 output application/xml --- payload.file]">
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="de3f5603-a0e4-4234-b5bc-b61ab52b74db" message="File output: #[payload]"></logger>
</foreach>

Comment: Please update the question to add the error. Avoid adding error/code in the comments wheever possible as they are not readable

Comment: It is the same error. I have pasted details in the comment.

Comment: I know, I am saying you should update the question to add this error instead of adding in the comments

Comment: When posting Mule errors please add as much of of the error in the logs as possible. Just posting the descriptive text misses other debug information.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the flow:

1. `file.record`: is not a collection in the sense that collectionPath needs. `file` is a sequence of similar elements to iterate.
2. `collection="#[%dw 2.0 &#10;output application/xml &#10;--- &#10;payload.file]"`: output to XML doesn't make sense. It would need to be converted again inside the loop. It only makes sense if you want to use `deferred` for streaming the output. See below.
3. The error about `Trying to output second root` is caused by emitting a list of 'records' without a root as XML.

Reading the documentation on [DataWeave Streaming](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-streaming#stream_xml) I came up with this alternative:

```xml
    <flow name="dw-xml-streamingFlow">
        <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler">
            <scheduling-strategy >
                <fixed-frequency frequency="5" timeUnit="MINUTES"/>
            </scheduling-strategy>
        </scheduler>
        <file:read doc:name="Read" config-ref="File_Config" path="path\to\input.xml" outputMimeType="application/xml; streaming=true; collectionpath=file">
            <non-repeatable-stream />
        </file:read>

        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message">
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[
                    %dw 2.0
                    input payload application/xml               
                    output application/xml deferred=true
                    ---
                    payload.&file
                ]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        
        <foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[payload.file]">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]"/>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
```

Note that the streaming property is only used to parse the input but a `deferred`property in an output is needed to send a stream to the next component in the flow. I used the transform for that.

You can add the batch attribute to the foreach as desired.

Using the key-value select (`&`) the expression returns the key in addition to the values to avoid the second root error.

The foreach is only needed if you are trying to do something with each record, like sending an API request. If you want to transform the data it would be more efficient to do so inside the transform in a single DataWeave script without a foreach.

Comment: Thank you Aled, but foreach shape still has the same expression error, it complains about "payload.file.*record". Also, on point 2, file is more like a root element in the xml, it won't be repeating.

Comment: Please update the question with the updated flow and error details. Did you remove the output... statement from the collection attribute?

Comment: About collectionPath (point 2 above), it should point to the element that contains the elements to stream, not to the contained elements. See the example at https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-streaming#stream_xml. In your case is the root element.

Comment: Added a transform shape before foreach to convert it to JSON and then foreach was able to iterate through the payload.file.*record. This time it was successfully completing the flow.
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="1d7577db-b5b1-49ec-b2be-9b0c4810031b" >
   <ee:message >
    <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
@StreamCapable()
input payload application/xml
output application/json
---
vars.varsXML]]></ee:set-payload>

Comment: Converting between formats in the middle of a flow consumes more memory and CPU while reducing performance. Also probably it may not fully stream in the way that you are expecting.

Comment: Clarification of the terminology: foreach is a scope, transform is a transformer, not just shapes.

Comment: what do you suggest then? is there a way to rectify the expression error in foreach.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example solution and updated my observations based on the documentation.

Comment: Did you try the updated answer?